# Magento Multi Theme Styling

Tags: multistore, rwd-theme, theme-fallback

I've a multistore setup which is using a custom base theme for the structure but the colour scheme is to change per store. Is it possible to fall back to the base theme but only modify _var.scss per store?

Comment: Do you want to use RWD as your base theme

Comment: I am using a custom theme (called PDT) based of RWD. I then have 3 more store views which need to be based off the custom theme PDT but with a different colour scheme. All colour changes come out of _var.scss. I've got the templates working OK, it's the css which is the issue. Do I need to copy all the scss files for each store or can I reference the main PDT scss and only change the _var.scss file per store. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: If you take a look at the link i posted in my answer. This runs through compiling sass from rwd parent theme, you can follow this same method but use rwd/yourcustomtheme as the parent theme instead of rwd/default. To compile sass you basically need to add import path into your sass config.rb which points to your custom themes sass directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll have a read of that article and let you know how I get on.

Comment: No probs it helped me get my head around building from rwd, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RWD as your parent and base your multi store themes off of this using Magentos theme fallback

This is a really useful step by step guide on how you can achieve this

http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Nirvana_Wiese_ClassyLlama_Fitness%20Center_Final.pdf

Comment: This was very helpful. The priority order of the import paths was the key. I imported RWD first then my custom PDT theme.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible using Magento it's fallback system. In your new theme with the seperate color schemes you can define a fallback in a theme.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

There might be more useful options out there but this is the only obvious way I know.

For more information on theme fallback please refer to http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml

Comment: Great in-depth article :) Learnt a lot from it. Thank you.